# Find contacting and non-contacting part of two strings

Tags: python, string

I have two examples of pair of strings

```
YHFLSPYVY      # answer
   LSPYVYSPR   # prediction
+++******ooo


  YHFLSPYVS    # answer
VEYHFLSPY      # prediction
oo*******++
```

As stated above I'd like to find the overlapping region (`*`) and non-overlapping region in answer (`+`) and prediction (`o`).

How can I do it in Python?

I'm stuck with this

```
import re
# This is of example 1
ans = "YHFLSPYVY"
pred= "LSPYVYSPR"
matches = re.finditer(r'(?=(%s))' % re.escape(pred), ans)
print [m.start(1) for m in matches]
#[]
```

The answer  I hope to get for example 1 is:

```
plus_len = 3
star_len = 6
ooo_len = 3
```

Comment: Do you want the first overlap? Or the longest overlap?

Comment: Do you also want the string with *+o or just the values of plus_len etc.?

Comment: Looks like [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

Comment: Will a single character common to both also be considered an overlap?

Comment: @AnupamMohanty: Just the values of `plus_len` etc.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: yes

Comment: Are you aligning protein sequences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy with [`difflib.SequenceMatcher.find_longest_match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.find_longest_match):

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def f(answer, prediction):
    sm = SequenceMatcher(a=answer, b=prediction)
    match = sm.find_longest_match(0, len(answer), 0, len(prediction))
    star_len = match.size
    return (len(answer) - star_len, star_len, len(prediction) - star_len)
```

The function returns a 3-tuple of integers `(plus_len, star_len, ooo_len)`:

```
f('YHFLSPYVY', 'LSPYVYSPR') -> (3, 6, 3)
f('YHFLSPYVS', 'VEYHFLSPY') -> (2, 7, 2)
```

Comment: SO is like an army of super intelligent minds, not even a second and the question was answered :D !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `difflib`:

```
import difflib

ans = "YHFLSPYVY"
pred = "LSPYVYSPR"

def get_overlap(s1, s2):
     s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, s1, s2)
     pos_a, pos_b, size = s.find_longest_match(0, len(s1), 0, len(s2))
     return s1[pos_a:pos_a+size]

overlap = get_overlap(ans, pred)
plus = ans.replace(get_overlap(ans, pred), "")
oo = pred.replace(get_overlap(ans, pred), "")

print len(overlap)
print len(plus)
print len(oo)
```